# Javascript on ASP generated page malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm new to classic ASP, so I'm probably missing something simple.

I have a Classic ASP Page running some JavaScript to handle events on a series of check-boxes. When I take the generated HTML and paste it into its own page, the JavaScript works as intended, but on the ASP I'm getting bugs.

I'm guessing it has to do with when things are loaded onto the page, but I'm not sure. I've attached my JavaScript and the ASP page below:

**ASP Code**

http://pastebin.com/hKgfMRPc

**JavaScript**

http://pastebin.com/sbGhRy1V

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are starting out I'd drop the classic ASP and learn .NET.  If .net seems a little overwhelming, try PHP as it has a lot of design similarities with classic ASP but is more supported.  Classic ASP is really getting on now!

Also, at the top of each page, you should have:

```
<% Option Explicit %>
```

This should be always used, as it makes debugging 10x easier, it throws errors when you redefine variables, and other useful things.  Put it on every page, even during release.

Also dimension you variables, this is another way of saying 'declare your variables.  So your ASP page should look like:

```
<%
    Option Explicit

    Dim xml
    Dim strReturnedText
%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
....
```

Also, don't forget to drop your objects, or they will remain in memory.  Change your function to read like this:

```
<%
    'Load XML
    set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xml.async = false
    xml.load(Server.MapPath("/site-index.xml"))

    'Load XSL
    set xsl = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xsl.async = false
    xsl.load(Server.MapPath("/site-index.xsl"))

    'Get the response
    strReturnedText = xml.transformNode(xsl)

    'Clean up the object
    set xml = nothing

    'Transform file
    Response.Write(strReturnedText)
%>
```

Because you haven't given us an error message, it's hard to debug your code for you.  If you paste the error message you get after making these changes, it should be very easy to pinpoint it for you.

**Edit**

In response to your comment with the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

This might throw errors as you are trying to print out the actual XML file which the browser might get confused about as it is rendering an HTML document.

Try wrapping the output in `<xmp>` tags a temporary test to see if it resolves the problem:

```
'Transform file
Response.Write("<xmp>" & strReturnedText & "</xmp>")
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. It seems like you'd need to put the set xml = nothing below the xml.transformNode, so I went ahead and did that. I also set xsl = nothing at that point too

Here's the HTML that is generated by the ASP page: 
http://pastebin.com/STP9pe0p

You'll notice that the check-box 'opener' filters the list items by the 'opener' class, and only one shows up. In the ASP page, all the items disappear no matter what you click on.

Comment: Wrapping the xmp tag around the output makes the page only render the XML, as plaintext. The rest of the HTML is only visible in the source.

Comment: @User yes it was meant to do that, it's just to check if stops the error appearing as you have then pinpointed the cause of it.  What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I apologize for the delay- there is no explicit error being thrown. The Javascript is just failing to correctly filter the li's